# Is it possible to add text underneath a part's title?

Tags: sectioning, parts, text-manipulation, report

In a LaTeX report I'm working on, I have used `\part{title of part}` to organise the chapters into parts.

This gives me distinct pages for each `\part` specified which is what I want. But if I try to add text beneath the part's title, it is printed on the next page.

Is it possible to place text on the `\part` page directly under the title of the part?

Thanks Christian. The part pages now look something like what you see below with text added. The only other thing will be to try to move the text up a bit.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There seems to be a `\newpage` at the end of `part` command, which has to be *kicked* out, by relaxing it temporarily, in a group.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}


\makeatletter

\let\LaTeXStandardPart\part%
\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@noopt}[1]{%
  \unstarredpart@@opt[#1]{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredpart@@opt}[2][]{%
  \cleardoublepage% (For clearing content before!!!)
  \begingroup%
  \let\newpage\relax%
  \LaTeXStandardPart[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup%
}%

\newcommand{\starredpart}[1]{%
  \LaTeXStandardPart*{#1}%
}%

\newcommand{\unstarredpart}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\unstarredpart@@opt}{\unstarredpart@@noopt}%
}%

\renewcommand{\part}{%
  \@ifstar{\starredpart}{\unstarredpart}%
}%

\begin{document}

\part{Some part}%
\blindtext[10]

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}%

\blindtext

\part{Other part}
\chapter{Other chapter}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @MrMorgan: Please unaccept -- there is an error!

Comment: @MrMorgang: Thanks! I found the error: The ToC wasn't shown due to the relaxing of newpage. Now it's ok (I think!)

Comment: Question modified to show the results.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer is there a way to fix the position of  Part and its title?
I wanna put it at a fix poistion at the top of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Lesser code with `xpatch`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@endpart}{\vfil\newpage}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@endpart}{\newpage}{}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Some part}%
\blindtext[10]

\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}%

\blindtext

\part{Other part}
\chapter{Other chapter}%

\end{document}
```

[image]